# Не работает clip-path в IE 11.0.120

Tags: css, css3, svg, internet-explorer, clip-path

Всем привет!
 Много гуглил, пробовал. Не работает `clip-path`, не могу разобраться почему.
 Ниже прилагаю код, который воспроизводит мою проблему. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю? В Google `Chrome` всё хорошо. В `Firefox` тоже всё хорошо. В IE 11 и Edge вообще не работает.

```css
.child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 20px;
 background: limegreen;
 clip-path: url("#clipping");
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
   <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0 0,.8 0,1 1,.2 1"></polygon>
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Всем, заранее, спасибо за предложенные варианты решения этой проблемы!

Comment: этим свойством никак https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: смотрите раздел совместимости с браузерами

Comment: в Вашем случае наверняка можно аоспользоваться альтернативными способами обоезки

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в том-то и дело, там в самом низу пометка, что работать должно с url (Internet Explorer only supports clip paths defined by url().)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ но если посоветуете другой вариант, который реализуют такую же обрезку по трапеции, то я с радостью рассмотрю и его

Comment: а обязательна именно обрезка? что в итоге должно получиться?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ именно трапеция и внутри текст, я уже думаю, может проще обычным бэкграундом сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вариант без обрезок

```css
.skew {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.skew.left, .skew.right div {
   transform: skewX(25deg);
}

.skew.right, .skew.left div {
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
}

.skew div {
  margin-left: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:wheat;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew left">
   <div>123456</div>
</div>
<div class="skew right">
   <div>654321</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо! Пометил ответ как верный и лайкнул!

Comment: @MarkKhromov только это не трапеция а параллелограмм

Comment: Да, точно! У меня что-то в голове трапеция-трапеция :D Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В комментариях уже ответили, что clip-path в `IE` не работает

https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Лайкнул ваш ответ! Спасибо!

Comment: @MaximLensky Привет! Если у тебя работает clip-path CSS в `IE` вопреки [CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) размести please свой вариант ответом здесь.

Answer (score 2):

На svg clip-path работает везде ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 229 71" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="clipPath833">
   <path d="m-135 63h175l54 38-54 33h-175z" style="fill:#00ff00;paint-order:markers fill stroke"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(135 -63)">
  <image x="-135" y="8" width="329" height="213" clip-path="url(#clipPath833)" style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQKDK.jpg"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: там речь про clip-path для не svg элементов

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0k17bmL

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да ..восстановил как для примера SVG так как работает везде

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо за ответ! Но для моего случая не подойдет, не могу позволить себе делать обертку для каждого элемента. Но ваш ответ всё равно лайкну!

Comment: @MarkKhromov там ни надо для каждого элемента оборачивать ..я просто ответил в рамках этого ответа ...а конкретно SVG хватит одного ... а использовать можно кучу раз

Comment: @MaximLensky разве? Мне бы пришлось обернуть каждого моего чилда в svg, чтобы использовать этот clip-path :( Понимаю, что инициализировать его можно и один раз

Comment: @MarkKhromov а как же use ? это дубликат ...можно использовать кучу раз ...ваш clip-path можно не использовать ..но хотя ваше дело

Comment: @MaximLensky о, про use, вроде, не слышал еще, скинете инфу какую-нибудь?

Comment: @MarkKhromov  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо! Не знал про это, изучу!

Comment: @MarkKhromov если что то не ясно пишите в рубрику SVG

Comment: @MaximLensky хорошо! Спасибо!