# Подскажите, как сделать блок со скошенными углами и бордером

Tags: css, блок

[image: блок со скошенными углами]

Подскажите, как сделать блок со скошенными углами и бордером. внутри текст. Если применить transform skew, то текст тоже скашивает.

Comment: нужно к тексту применить обратный skew https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/972155/188366

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: Вложить текст в еще один блок и применить к нему обратную трансформацию:

```css
.outer {
  padding: 1em;
  background: blue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
}

.inner {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">text</div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2: громоздить псевдоэлемент (зеленая тень - для наглядности, показывает сам блок с текстом):

```css
.skew {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px green inset;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.skew:after {
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew">text</div>
```

Comment: текст выносить в отельный блок не вариант

Comment: тогда  придется громоздить что-то еще...

Comment: добавил вариант